# MongoDB and Java driver: "ignore case" in query

Tags: java, mongodb, case-insensitive

This is the code I'm using now, how do I add the "ignore case" attribute?

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("prop", value);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When I had the exact problem, I wasn't able to query by ignoring case. I ended up copy the value that I wanted to search normalizing it. In this case, you can create a new property and convert it to lower case and have an index on that.

**EDIT:**

```
DBObject ref = new BasicDBObject();
ref.put("myfield", Pattern.compile(".*myValue.*" , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
DBCursor cur = coll.find(ref);
```

I wonder if that works?

Comment: This was version 1.4 by the way. Maybe things have changed now.

Comment: Playing with the console, I realized that typing db.collection.find({"prop":/value/i}) makes my query case insensitive. There must be a way to enable the "i" attribute using the Java driver, even if through a Regex query it doesn't matter. Typing DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("prop", "/" + value + "/i") doesn't work though.

Comment: Give that a try. I hope its what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

In case if you are using Spring-java below mentioned is the way you can make it search in case-insensitive manner.

```
public List<Discussion> searchQuestionByText(String qText){
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("discussionName").regex(qText,"i"));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Discussion.class);     
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I was also trying to get the best use of the implementation "case insensitive".
If you're using the [MongoDB Java driver 3.0](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/) or later, you should use this following code, with the  **$option** parameter ! It's really easy to use:

```
Document basicQuery = new Document();
basicQuery.append("key", new Document("$regex","value").append("$options","i"));
```

The fields "key" and "value" need to be changed with your own data.

(I also advise you to search with **$regex** parameter in order to retrieve information via partial matching in the case you would have more and more records in the database).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.iolog.find({$where:"this.firstname.toLowerCase()==\"telMan\".toLowerCase()"});
DBObject ref = new BasicDBObject();
ref.append("firstname", new BasicDBObject("$where","this.firstname.toLowerCase()=="+firstname+".toLowerCase()"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 mapValue = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 mapValue.put("$options", "i");
 mapValue.put("$regex", "smth");
 searchMap.put("name", mapValue);
 collection.find(new BasicDBObject(searchMap));
```