# How to make a case-insensitive query in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I know make case-insensitive query in console could use regex like `db.stuff.find( { foo: /bar/i } );`

[MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

But I cannot fiure out how to use it in java drive.example:

```
DBObject q = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add(type, s).add("user", user).get();
DBCursor cursor = c.find(q);
```

I want `user` case-insensitive,How to do that?

Comment: You should look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069340/mongodb-and-java-driver-ignore-case-in-query

Comment: @lowercase Eh...I didn't find it.But thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already aware of using regular expression. The only other option I can think of would be to  normalize the data to be queried.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Pattern.compile() where the first param is the value you are querying for and the second param is Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE as below.

```
query.put("db.variable", Pattern.compile(searchValueHere, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```