# MongoDB: Case Insensitive search (Java)

Tags: java, mongodb, case-sensitive

```
BasicDBObject Search = new BasicDBObject();
Search.put("name", UName);
MongoCursor<Document> mongoCursor = TestCollection.find(Search).iterator();
```

I've seen a few ways online but most of them are 2 years or so old. Some don't work with the `BasicDBObject` search as well. What is the correct way of going about it now? I'm using the `mongodb java driver 3.2`.

Comment: duplicate of ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069340/mongodb-and-java-driver-ignore-case-in-query

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow David! Try to be more expressive on your questions. See if Melgart's message helps you, and feel free to ask your doubts here! See yah! ;)